# Is there a way to federate several macbook microphones to act as a single microphone?

Tags: macos, audio, microphone

I've a problem. When I'm in the office, all of us have a MacBook but only one call can have a zoom call running otherwise there is an echo.

Is there a way to connect all the other microphones to the same computer so to have just one zoom call running but even people far from the main computer can be heard?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want all the audio from the microphones on the MacBooks to be *routed* to a single MacBook?  Have you thought about getting a conference room video call setup?  This is what they were designed for.

Comment: If you don't mind running microphone cables that device is called a "mixer" or if you prefer an "audio mixer" and are common devices that allow multiple microphone and/or line-level audio sources to be combined and their individual volumes adjusted and fed into one output that could then be fed into a Mac (or PC). I would imagine that searching for "microphone mixer" would turn up thousands of possibilities. These devices are routinely used to produce music, live or recorded so some are **very expensive** but I would bet something to suit your budget could be found.

Comment: Just thinking here… you could mute the speakers of all the MacBooks except the main one to eliminate feedback.  Then use “bigger” speakers on the main until so everyone can hear.  It’s a complete bodge and depends on everyone complying, but this could work.

Comment: That's a form of separating the speakers from the microphone @Allan - feel free to edit my geometry bullet or make it an edit if you don't want to prop up a full on answer...

Comment: Thanks @bmike - I’m hesitant to do so; it’s such a shot-from-the hip that I don’t think it would hold up as an answer at present.  Maybe if we get some feedback from the OP, it would fit within your geometry bullet point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical solution to this is to have each person with microphones near their mouth and far from the speaker so that the feedback and echo is managed.

You can do this most easily with wired microphones to each computer or have people join using cell phones / smart tablets, etc...

The latency added by all the microphones having a different delay and the processing time guarantees your hypothetical solution will be even worse than the current situation where the software tries to minimize this echo as best the software / hardware can and your geometry is just too hard a problem to overcome.

- change the geometry (mic close to mouth / far from speaker - separate the speakers)
- use headphones instead of speaker (another form of "separating the speakers")
- buy hardware that has custom audio processing at low latency to isolate each speaker in the room

  - https://owllabs.com
  - https://www.jabra.com/business/speakerphones/jabra-speak-series/jabra-speak-710##7710-409 (this works so much better than the price would make you expect - we've had 25+ people in too large a room for this device to work as speaker and mic and it was almost as good as a $10,000 in-room custom install for our needs and it covered a room larger than the custom meeting room)